# Regex browser search?

Tags: regex, firefox, search, google-chrome, browser

Is there a way to use the "find" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>) function or something similar in a browser, but use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to search?

I have been looking through add-ons and the such, but I can't find anything to suit my needs. I have found tools to search the HTML source, but that's not as useful.

Comment: Nice Question. was looking for it

Comment: Nice question, but should be on superuser.com instead of SO

Comment: On Super User (with a new answer for the Firefox Quantum juggernaut): *[How do I search a page using a regular expression in Firefox?](https://superuser.com/questions/208652/how-do-i-search-a-page-using-a-regular-expression-in-firefox/1343668#1343668)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's the Chrome extension [Regular Expresson Searcher](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jghefebighmdikapmalhddkoldecjajk):

> Search web pages using regular expressions
>
> This extensions allows you to search web pages using regular expression.  It uses VI-style
>   keystrokes.

and a slightly older and lower-rated extension, [Regular Expression Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/haocppnjhmfiemhgfdgockbipphbfibe):

> Search Page with Regular Expression
>
> A simple search utility that
>   allows you to search a web page using regular expression.

Comment: These didn't work for me. I wrote my own open source extension to solve the issue: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/regex-search/bcdabfmndggphffkchfdcekcokmbnkjl?hl=en&gl=US

Comment: @gsingh2011 - Any chance of porting this to Firefox?

Comment: @user66001 I have no clue how to write a Firefox extension and I don't have time now to learn how. If you or anyone is interested in porting it to Firefox (it might be that all the code will work fine but only needs to be moved around), I'd be happy to answer any questions about the code or how the extension works. The best place to post these questions would probably be by creating a new issue called "Firefox port" on Github.